# Compile SweetJS to String in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sweet.js

From the shell, I can call the Sweet.js compiler.

`sjs -m macro-providing-module -o output-directory/file.js input-directory/file.sjs`

How can I do the same from inside a Node.js module such that instead of outputting to a specified file, I get the compiled output as a string?

```
var sweetjs = require('sweet.js');
var input = require('fs').readSync('input-directory/file.sjs');
var module = 'macro-providing-module';

var output = sweetjs(/* ??? */);
```

Comment: There's `sweetjs.compile()` that does that, but I don't have a clue on how to implement the module-loading part. The API doesn't seem to be documented and the code is pretty unreadable :(

Comment: Yeah, I went through the code, and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: In case anybody was wondering why I want to do this, I'm trying to write the `fez-sweet.js` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its undocumented because it will be changed/removed when sweet.js gets good module support (using ES6 `import`s instead of command line flags). But for 0.4.0 you can use the following API to load macros from npm modules:

```
var sweet = require('sweet.js');
var mod = sweet.loadNodeModule(root, modulePath);
var out = sweet.compile(<contents>, {
    modules: [mod]
});
```

The `root` argument is the location on the file system to start looking for node modules. Generally this is `process.cwd()` if you are making a command line tool or something. `compile` takes an options object where you can provide an array of `module`s.

If you just want to compile a string as a module, you can use `sweet.loadModule(<contents>)`.

Again, this API is merely a stop-gap and will be removed in the near future.

Edit: corrected the `compile` API